# Using API-Key in Vapor

Tags: vapor

I'm developing a simple web API with Vapor. To give more context, I'm newbie in backend development.

The consumer of the API is going to be an iOS app. Currently, I don't need the users to sign up to use the app. And I would like to keep it like that.

On the other hand, I would like to have some authentication to avoid that anyone could use the API I'm developing.

Looking for information I've found how implement authentication. But the examples I've seen are based on creating users in the backend for each user of the app. What I don't want to do. I would like to use an api-key as we do normally when we use third-party api's.

How could I have "api-key authentication" with Vapor ??

Or, should I just create an unique user/password that it's shared by all the users of the iOS app (that use the API) and then use basic or token authentication?

Thank you very much!

Carlos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way around this is to create a fake token and use either the `TokenAuthenticationMiddleware` or more likely a custom middleware that checks the incoming token.

However, be aware that there is nothing stopping anyone from inspecting the traffic coming from your app to view the token and then using that to access your API.

Comment: Agreed, only thing that would mitigate downside of inspecting traffic is using cert pinning. But I doubt this application calls for that level of security.

Comment: Thanks Tim! One question (maybe silly). About someone inspecting the traffic coming from my app. I would have this problem always, right? I mean, even if I implemented full authentication, someone could inspect the traffic and get the token of an specific user, couldn't they?

Comment: Yeah cert pinning is one way around it, but you can still decompile the app and pull out the key. There are barriers you can put up but it’s essentially impossible to completely stop it.

Comment: @Carlos yeah you’d always have the issue. However with full authentication then you require users to provide credentials to get a key. That means you can lock it down better. For instance you don’t have a global key that can do everything, you can add authorisation so that API key can interact with only certain parts. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the traffic is over ssl, then the headers would be encrypted and the token would not be visible to traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Following Tim idea and an example from the book *Server Side with Vapor* (by the Raywenderlich.com Tutorial Team) I've created this custom middleware that makes the work:

```
final class SecretMiddleware: Middleware {

let secret: String

init(secret: String) {
    self.secret = secret
}

func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Future<Response> {

    guard let bearerAuthorization = request.http.headers.bearerAuthorization else {
        throw Abort(.unauthorized, reason: "Missing token")
    }

    guard bearerAuthorization.token == secret else {
        throw Abort(.unauthorized, reason: "Wrong token")
    }

    return try next.respond(to: request)
}
}
extension SecretMiddleware: ServiceType {

static func makeService(for worker: Container) throws -> SecretMiddleware {

    let secret: String
    switch worker.environment {
    case .development:
        secret = "foo"
    default:
        guard let envSecret = Environment.get("SECRET") else {
            let reason = "No SECRET set on environment."
            throw Abort(.internalServerError, reason: reason)
        }
        secret = envSecret
    }
    return SecretMiddleware(secret: secret)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the book recommendation. However your code is misleading because you check for Bearer Authorization token, not for Api-Key. The question is about an app without user handling, there is no need to use Bearer tokens here.